# how can i input json file on mysql database?

Tags: mysql, json

```
[
{"link":"https://twitter.com/GreenAddress/status/550793651186855937",
"pDate":"2015 01 1",
"title":"GreenAddress",
"description": "btcarchitect coinkite blockchain circlebits coinbase bitgo some maybe some are oracle cosigners which require lesszero trust"},

{"link":"https://twitter.com/Bit_Swift/status/550765718581411840",
"pDate":"2015 01 1",
"title":"Bitswift™",
"description": "swiftstealth offers you privacy in  bitswift v2   swiftstealth enables stealth address use on the bitswift blockchain   swift"},

{"link":"https://twitter.com/allenday/status/550741133500772352",
"pDate":"2015 01 1",
"title":"Allen Day, PhD",
"description": "all in one article  bitcoin blockchain 3dprinting drones and deeplearninghttp simondlr compost101071618938adecentralizedaivia simondlr"}
]
```

my test.json file like this

[image]

and my mysql db table is here

i can input text file with csv type, but i have no idea how input json text file on mysql
i try [`create table test ( data json);`] and 
[`insert into test values ( '{json type}');` but when i try input data with csv type `LOAD DATA INFILE 'test.txt'` made it possible
so I wonder json has the same functionality

thanks for any advice

Comment: This is not a text file. Is a json. Create a JSON type column and store it.

Comment: Mysql doesn't support insert data using JSON like you would normally do using CSV. You can work on JSON **IF** *that's a big IF* your column type JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL does have JSON data field. However, it will not work with your file and current table structure as it [request a field to be JSON](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html). To solve your data, will require a little bit of programming work. Depending on your current ability, you will need to write codes that does the following:

1. Open a database connection
2. Read the JSON and loop through each value
3. Store each value using the following INSERT query:

   ```
   INSERT INTO news(link, date, title, description) VALUES($link, $pDate, $title, $description);
   ```
4. Depending on your language and database connection feature, close the database connection.

Comment: i try  [create table test ( data json);]   and [insert into test values ( '{json type}'); but when i try input data with csv type LOAD DATA INFILE 'test.txt'  made it possible

Comment: As I've said above, mysql doesn't support input data using JSON.

Comment: thanks, I'm going to build a macro with python script